# "New login" on the profile page is confusing UI

Tags: bug, status-completed, openid, user-interface, profile-page

It's purpose is not clear and people looking to associate a new openid with their account can't find it.  Perhaps it should be called "Associate another openid" or something like that.

Here is a user experience reported on HN: http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=873261

Comment: It is indeed rather unintuitive.

Comment: Good point from the linked site: *I had conceptualized as my goal as edit my OpenID and was therefore seeking for it **on the edit page**, not the main profile page.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I agree, this totally sucked, and I have nobody to blame but myself. I guess when I wrote that, I picked the wrong day to stop sniffing glue.

It now says **add openid** when you don't have an alt openid set, and **change openid** when you have both a primary and alt set.

There's also (theoretically) helpful title tooltip set on the links which elaborates a bit on the above.

Comment: Magic markers work just as well.

Comment: the scented ones are really nice though. Just lock me in a room with the orange scented magic marker and an internet connection, and I'm good for a few days.

Comment: That was fast... Thanks! 

Another related UI cleanup would be to shift (swap) to in front of the primary openid and adding a (remove) to the alternate id. But perhaps I should add that to a more relevant discussion.